# does javafx has built in audio capture?

Tags: java, audio, javafx, javafx-8, audio-capture

I know there is a duplicate question right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852309/javafx-support-for-microphone-audio-capture), but it's **obsolete**, so does `javafx` support audio capture.

Does it have any audio capturing API or interfaces, i know of `AudioClip` in `javafx.scene.media`. but it's only for playback.

Comment: I don't see how this is connected to JavaFX in any way.
Read more about capturing audio in Java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JavaFX 8 does not have an audio capture API.

There is an existing feature request (currently scheduled for implementation in Java 9):

- [JDK-8090438 Camera and Microphone](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090438)

For now, you can use the existing [javax.sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/) (which will probably work just fine from a JavaFX application), as suggested in Robin Jonsson's coment.