# Silence detection while recording in JavaFX

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I'm desperately trying to detect silence when recording on my JavaFX application. I'm using JavaSound API to record audio files.

Does someone has suggestions?

Hoping someone will reply soon, thanks in advance!

Comment: This has potential to be a good question. Be more detailed and specific about your problem and post your code attempt. As it stands, this question does not meet `StackOverFlow's` standards.

Comment: I personally think you should investigate one of Java's speech-to-text APIs. I am guessing that they may be better than the standard Java Sound API. https://github.com/lkuza2/java-speech-api

Comment: JavaFX doesn't have any kind of [audio capture API](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091858).  See also: [does javafx has built in audio capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490331/does-javafx-has-built-in-audio-capture)